# How to draw table with merged cells using Apose.Words

Tags: merge, cells, aspose, aspose.words

I have a problem with drawing table using Aspose.Words

So I need to get this result table:
   **-[link to proper table view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6DtUNGOC0VfUlN3UEVFV3lIUmM/view?usp=sharing) -**

To draw this table I've written the next code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

Table table = builder.startTable();

builder.insertCell();
builder.write("ROW 1");

builder.insertCell();
builder.getCellFormat().setHorisontalMerge(CellMerge.FIRST);
builder.write("VALUE 1");

builder.insertCell();
builder.getCellFormat().setHorisontalMerge(CellMerge.PREVIOUS);

builder.insertCell();
builder.getCellFormat().setHorisontalMerge(CellMerge.PREVIOUS);

builder.endRow();

// next row
builder.insertCell();
builder.write("ROW 2");

builder.insertCell();
builder.write("VLAUE 2_1");

builder.insertCell();
builder.write("VLAUE 2_2");

builder.insertCell();
builder.write("VLAUE 2_3");

builder.endRow();
builder.endTable()
```

But as usually in reality.. I'm getting next table:
**- [link to incorrect table view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6DtUNGOC0VfaU9jdktsOEo4MHM/view?usp=sharing)-**

My question is why cell 'VALUE 1' doesn't cover all "VALUE 2_*" cells from "ROW 2", why does it cover only one cell "VALUE 2_1"?
    And how can I draw proper table from my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, please upgrade to the [latest version of Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/72/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx) i.e. 15.6.0. Secondly, I have fixed your code as follows:

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

Table table = builder.startTable();

builder.insertCell();    
builder.write("ROW 1");

builder.insertCell();
builder.getCellFormat().setHorizontalMerge(CellMerge.FIRST);
builder.write("VALUE 1");

builder.insertCell();
builder.getCellFormat().setHorizontalMerge(CellMerge.PREVIOUS);

builder.insertCell();
builder.getCellFormat().setHorizontalMerge(CellMerge.PREVIOUS);

builder.endRow();

// next row
builder.insertCell();
builder.getCellFormat().setHorizontalMerge(CellMerge.NONE);
builder.write("ROW 2");

builder.insertCell();
builder.write("VLAUE 2_1");

builder.insertCell();
builder.write("VLAUE 2_2");

builder.insertCell();
builder.write("VLAUE 2_3");

builder.endRow();
builder.endTable();

doc.save(getMyDir() + "15.6.0.docx");
```

Hope, this helps.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.